# how to include qt directories and library with cmake

Tags: qt, cmake

here's my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# set the project name
project(calculateur_interest VERSION 0.01)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
#Qt5
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
#set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

set(src main.cpp;
        graph.cpp;
        mainwindow.cpp;
        resultat.cpp;
        mainwindow.ui;
        graph.ui;
        resultat.ui;
        )

add_library(source STATIC ${src} )

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Charts REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCharts")


add_executable(calc_int ${src})
target_link_libraries(calc_int Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Charts Qt5::Core)
```

after generating the MAKEFILE with cmake , i get this error:

```
64%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/source.dir/source_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
In file included from /home/pat/calculateur_interest/graph.h:5,
                 from /home/pat/calculateur_interest/build/source_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_graph.cpp:9,
                 from /home/pat/calculateur_interest/build/source_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp:2:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCharts/QtCharts:3:10: fatal error: QtCharts/QtChartsDepends: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <QtCharts/QtChartsDepends>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/source.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/source.dir/source_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:107: CMakeFiles/source.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

because of this line :

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCharts")
```

the compiler is looking in : `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCharts/QtCharts`

instead of : `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCharts`

if i dont put the include_directories i get this error :

```
64%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/source.dir/source_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
In file included from /home/pat/calculateur_interest/build/source_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_graph.cpp:9,
                 from /home/pat/calculateur_interest/build/source_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp:2:
/home/pat/calculateur_interest/graph.h:5:10: fatal error: QtCharts: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <QtCharts>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/source.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/source.dir/source_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:107: CMakeFiles/source.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

looks like iam including the directory the wrong way , i have tried lots of different ways but not the right one yet
QT-cmake documentation is lacking examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find_package` command gives you everything you need for locating both Qt include directories and binaries, so you shouldn't need an explicit `include_directories` command for Qt at all.  The problem is that the include directories that are located via `find_package` are typically added to a target when you add the package to `target_link_libraries`.  By creating your static library with `add_library(source STATIC ${src} )` and not linking to the Qt libraries, the library does not get the necessary include paths.

You have a couple ways of fixing this:

1. You could change your `include_directories` command to only use the root of the Qt include directory, i.e. change it to `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5")` - this should allow your `source` target to build, although given that it doesn't link to the Qt libraries itself, any other target linking to it would still need to link all the Qt dependencies explicitly
2. You could extract the value for the included directories set by the `find_package` commands, using the `get_property(TARGET ${target} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)` command, and then use those to populate the `include_directories(...)` command in your CMake file
3. The better solution - put the `source` target after the `find_package` commands, link the Qt libraries to the `source` target, and then if you make an executable that links to `source` it needs to ONLY link to that single static library, the rest of the dependencies will propagate - I also made the assumption that `main.cpp` is only needed for the executable and not the library.

```
set(src
        graph.cpp;
        mainwindow.cpp;
        resultat.cpp;
        mainwindow.ui;
        graph.ui;
        resultat.ui;
        )

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Charts REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_library(source STATIC ${src} )
target_link_libraries(source Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Charts Qt5::Core)

add_executable(calc_int main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(calc_int source)
```

4. You could simply remove your `source` static library target entirely, if you're only trying to create the executable, because your exe is setup and linked correctly as is

Comment: my QT version is 5.12 and i think its requiring to include directories from the find_package()

Comment: The `include_directories` commands are only needed if you are NOT linking the libraries as well.  As I said in my answer, the reason that this target: `add_library(source STATIC ${src} )` is not getting the includes added automatically is because you are not calling `target_link_libraries` on it.

Comment: It seems like the relying on `target_link_libraries` isn't very error-proof. I have a CMakeLists that works on Fedora 36, but not on Ubuntu 20.04. Qt includes are not being added (like, not even QObject... I think I'd notice if I hadn't even linked the core libraries).

Comment: find_package gives nothing for qt6 and it can't find anything because qt is installed in non standard path

Answer (score 3):

thanks rdowell i think its missing one line in your answer to make it work

heres my CMakeLists that is working :

```
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)   
    set(src main.cpp;
            mainwindow.cpp;
            resultat.cpp;
            mainwindow.ui;
            resultat.ui;
            graph.cpp
            graph.ui
            )
    
    include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
    add_library(source STATIC ${src} ) #all cpp and ui files
    #dependencies
    find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED))
    find_package(Qt5Charts REQUIRED)
    
    #dependencies directory headers
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCharts")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}) #special variable got from find_package() to include QtWidgets dependencies directories
    
    add_executable(calc_int ${src})#${charts_include_dir}
    #qt5_use_modules(calc_int Core Charts) # This macro depends from the Qt version
    target_link_libraries(calc_int PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Charts)
```

Comment: The two include_directories() commands are not needed

Comment: yes they are:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/cmake-manual.html

Comment: Again I think your problem is that you have two separate targets in your CMake file: a static library `source` and an executable `calc_int` - you're only calling `target_link_libraries` on the executable, which propagates all the necessary include directories to it, but not on the library.  This was why my answer suggested calling `target_link_libraries(source Qt5_Core Qt5_Widgets ...)` and then `target_link_libraries(calc_int source)`

Comment: It's not - the imported target takes care for it when you link against it as @rdowell correctly suggested - when you use a library you should link against it.

Comment: since my code was working i read in diagnal rdowell solution... you were both right, my apologies, and rdowell solution is better thank you all